# Stuck on convergence of $\sum\limits_{k= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{(k!)^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been stuck with showing the convergence of the sum $$\sum\limits_{k= 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{(k!)^2}}$$for a while now. Quotient and root criterion both are inconclusive, and the inequality $k! \leq k^k$ goes in the wrong direction for a majorization type argument. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Can you use stirling approximation for the factorial function?

Comment: The quotient and root criterion won't help here since they test the convergence against the geometric series, whereas your series have power series convergence which is much slower and geometric convergence cannot distinguish whether it converges or not. You may want to keep this in mind if you convergence is power series like, root or quotient tests won't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use the baby version of the Stirling's approximation,

$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[k]{k!}}{k} = \frac{1}{e},$$

then the convergence of the series immediately follows from the limit comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty$.

---

If you are not aware of the above result, still you can prove the convergence. Let $n_k = \lfloor k/3\rfloor$ and note that

$$ k!
= \prod_{i=1}^{k} i
\geq \prod_{i=n_k + 1}^{k} i
\geq \prod_{i=n_k + 1}^{k} (n_k + 1)
= (n_k + 1)^{k-n_k}
\geq (k/3)^{2k/3}. $$

Hence,

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[k]{(k!)^2}} \leq \frac{1}{(k/3)^{4/3}} $$

and we can apply the comparison test with the $p$-series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{4/3}} < \infty$.

(*Remark.* Note that this argument still works with $n_k = \lfloor \alpha k \rfloor$ for any $\alpha \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$. The above argument corresponds to $\alpha = \frac{1}{3}$.)